# PHP / SQL Equal to certain column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with my php and I can't figure out why it's not working.

I'm trying to only show rows where a certain column is equal to 0.

What I have right now:

```
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elebest
    WHERE 
    ( ( `BSTLIEFBST` LIKE '%".$query."%' )
    OR 
    ( `BSTKATNR` LIKE '%".$query."%' )
    OR 
    ( `BSTLIEFTXT` LIKE '%".$query."%' ) "  ) or die(mysql_error());
```

I tried multiple things and last thing I tried was:

```
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elebest
    WHERE 
    ( ( `BSTLIEFBST` LIKE '%".$query."%' )
    OR 
    ( `BSTKATNR` LIKE '%".$query."%' )
    OR 
    ( `BSTLIEFTXT` LIKE '%".$query."%' ) AND ( `BSTANF` = 0 ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

First Code works fine.. I just can't figure out why it says:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 7"

I read some tutorials about this but most of them just show `$function`. I don't have my columns as function in my php. I have them as:

```
.$results['BSTKATNR'].
```

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out on my own... i had an extra ( in my code..

Comment: You opened two brackets in line 3, closing just one in line 7. Try adding a closing bracket before the last `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets are misplaced. Here is your query with corrected syntax.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM elebest
WHERE 
(
    `BSTLIEFBST` LIKE '%".$query."%'
    OR 
    `BSTKATNR` LIKE '%".$query."%'
    OR 
    `BSTLIEFTXT` LIKE '%".$query."%'
)
AND `BSTANF` = 0";
```

Comment: yea.. thanks. i figured it out on my own after looking at the brackets :)

Comment: @Aldercy you should still flag this as correct, or delete the question